# Java 8 streams map, keep nulls as null

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream

I have this piece of code:

```
public LatLng[] locationDtoListToLatLngArray(List<LocationDto> locationDtoList) {
    return locationDtoList.stream()
            .map(locationDto -> new LatLng(locationDto.getLatitude(), locationDto.getLongitude()))
            .toArray(LatLng[]::new);
}
```

but is crashing if `locationDto` is `null` inside `.map`

I fixed it doing this:

```
public LatLng[] locationDtoListToLatLngArray(List<LocationDto> locationDtoList) {
    return locationDtoList.stream()
            .map(locationDto -> locationDto == null ? null : new LatLng(locationDto.getLatitude(), locationDto.getLongitude()))
            .toArray(LatLng[]::new);
}
```

but I want to know if there is a better approach (without checking if `locationDto == null`)

Please note that, if `locationDto == null`, I want to keep the `null`, so filter is not an option :)

Thanks

EDIT: I know that the problem is accessing a null object, I just want to know is if there is some function like `.map()`, that do what I need, `.mapKeepingNulls()`, something like that.

EDIT 2: I ended up doing this:

```
public LatLng[] locationDtoListToLatLngArray(List<LocationDto> locationDtoList) {
    return locationDtoList.stream()
            .map(this::locationDtoToLatLng)
            .toArray(LatLng[]::new);
}

private LatLng locationDtoToLatLng(LocationDto locationDto) {
    if (locationDto == null) {
        return null;
    }
    return new LatLng(locationDto.getLatitude(), locationDto.getLongitude());
}
```

Comment: A better approach than checking for `null`?

Comment: The side-question is: why do you have `null`s in the first place in a list? (And I don't think there's a cleaner way, aside from wrapping all of this in an `Optional`, which would be counterproductive IMO).

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, yes, I'm thinking that may be some function that do what I want.. .mapKeepingNulls() something like this.. I'm new with streams

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are accessing methods of a potentionally `null` value. If you really don't want the null check there (which I think is a good solution) you can try making a static method in `LatLng` that will take the `LocationDto` and return the right instance or `null` when the supplied `LocationDto` is `null`.

Something like this:

```
public static LatLng getFromLocationDto(LocationDto ldt){
    if(ldt == null)
        return null;

    return new LatLng(ldt.getLatitude(), ldt.getLongitude());
}
```

But the `null` check has to be somewhere (unless you can ensure that there will be no `null` int the `locationDtoList`).

Answer (score 0):

The issue as little to do with Java 8 streams. You are getting an `NullPointerException` when doing `locationDto.getLatitude()`.

It is totally normal to check for null value. If you were not in a stream, I am almost sure that you would have not disturbed you.

Maybe what you dislike is the fact that you are performing inline conditional operation in a one-liner, in which case I advise you to use an helper function like `_createLatLng(LocationDto locationDto)` to externalize that process.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of Optional, which is a new class in Java 8 made for this purpose.

// transform  locationDtoList to a list of Optional

```
locationDtoList.stream()
        .filter(Optional::isPresent)
        .map(Optional::get)
        .map(locationDto -> new LatLng(locationDto.getLatitude(),      locationDto.getLongitude()))
        .toArray(LatLng[]::new);
```